# node sass error after change sass file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass, node-sass

when I change any sass file in my project after that my project stopped working and in console return following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: (0 , h.default) is not a function`

I think it's from the version of node-sass and ...

Can anyone help me?

My `package.js` is:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "history": "^3.3.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "16.2.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^8.2.0",
    "autoprefixer-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-babili": "^0.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.29.0",
    "ignore-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.1.3",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.3",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.9",
    "webpack": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.1",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "^0.1.11"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give more details?

Comment: upload webpack.config and package.json

Comment: @GautamNaik updated